# PySide2 app that doesn't launch via VSCODE

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyside2

I tried to code a very simple currency converter app, so the script is supposed to open a window with a currency converter.

But when I run the file in the Python terminal via VS Code on my Mac, it opens a Python launcher window that does not respond.
When I open this script in IDLE and run it, It works perfectly (on my mac).

When I run the same file in the Python terminal via VS Code on my Windows10 Laptop, it works perfectly.

I use Python 3.9 and the same libraries (PySide2 and currencyConverter are installed on both devices)

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import currency_converter


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.c = currency_converter.CurrencyConverter()
        self.setWindowTitle("Convertisseur de devises")
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_connections()
        self.set_default_values()
        self.setup_css()
        self.resize(500, 50)

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.cbb_devisesFrom = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.le_montant = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.cbb_devisesTo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.le_montantConverti = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.btn_inverser = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Inverser devises")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.cbb_devisesFrom)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.le_montant)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cbb_devisesTo)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.le_montantConverti)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_inverser)

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.cbb_devisesFrom.activated.connect(self.compute)
        self.cbb_devisesTo.activated.connect(self.compute)
        self.le_montant.valueChanged.connect(self.compute)
        self.btn_inverser.clicked.connect(self.inverser_devises)

    def setup_css(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
        color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
        border: none;
        """)
        style = """
        QComboBox::down-arrow {
            image: none;
            border-width: 0px;
        }
        QComboBox::drop-down {
            border-width: 0px;
        } 
        """
        self.cbb_devisesFrom.setStyleSheet(style)
        self.cbb_devisesTo.setStyleSheet(style)

    def set_default_values(self):
        self.cbb_devisesFrom.addItems(sorted(list(self.c.currencies)))
        self.cbb_devisesTo.addItems(sorted(list(self.c.currencies)))
        self.cbb_devisesFrom.setCurrentText("EUR")
        self.cbb_devisesTo.setCurrentText("EUR")
        self.le_montant.setValue(100)
        self.le_montantConverti.setValue(100)
        self.le_montant.setRange(1, 1000000)
        self.le_montantConverti.setRange(1, 1000000)

    def compute(self):
        montant = self.le_montant.value()
        deviseFrom = self.cbb_devisesFrom.currentText()
        deviseTo = self.cbb_devisesTo.currentText()

        try:
            resultat = self.c.convert(montant, deviseFrom, deviseTo)
        except currency_converter.currency_converter.RateNotFoundError:
            print("Rate not found")
        else:
            self.le_montantConverti.setValue(resultat)

    def inverser_devises(self):
        devise_from = self.cbb_devisesFrom.currentText()
        devise_to = self.cbb_devisesTo.currentText()

        self.cbb_devisesFrom.setCurrentText(devise_to)
        self.cbb_devisesTo.setCurrentText(devise_from)
        self.compute()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
win = App()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: have you tried running it in a terminal?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping! Yes I tried and got this error :                                              achillederibreux@MacBook-Pro-de-Achille app % python App.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets
ImportError: No module named PySide2
achillederibreux@MacBook-Pro-de-Achille app % pip3.9 list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
currency.converter 0.5.5
CurrencyConverter  0.14.4
pip                20.3.3
PySide2            5.15.2
setuptools         49.2.1
shiboken2          5.15.2

Comment: seems like you have not installed that module, try running `pip install PySide2`

Comment: Hi ! thanks for helping me ! It tells me that it's already installed.. "Requirement already satisfied: PySide2 in..." and it works with Idle

Comment: i suspect  that you have multiple versions of python installed, try running it with python3, and with python

Comment: @Achille use `python3.9 -m pip install pyside2`

Comment: Hi, thanks everybody for helping me ! I found the solution and it was a bug between PySide2 and MacOs Big sur, I used the module mathplotlib and it works well now !

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command "`pip show PySide2`"(or "`pip3 show PySide2`") in the VS Code terminal to check whether the installation location of the module "PySide2" is consistent with the Python environment displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code:

[image]

If the results are inconsistent, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, and it will automatically enter the selected environment.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for helping me ! I found the solution and it was a bug between PySide2 and MacOs Big sur, I used the module mathplotlib and it works well now !